# Rust reuse moved struct instance

Tags: rust, antlr, antlr4

I am working on a grammar in AntLR and Rust and I need to implement an ErrorListener that collects syntax errors that I need to use later. If I use a custom listener that has an inner RefCell to a vector of failed token types when I pass it to the `parser.add_error_listener` I lose the ownership and I cannot extract errors anymore (`parser.add_error_listener` takes a Box and not a reference to the listener).

```
    let listener = MyErrorListener::new();
    parser.add_error_listener(Box::new(listener));
    let res = parser.query();
    lestener.errors() // here I get error from the compiler since I already moved listener above
```

How do I overcome this issue? Is there a way to reuse the listener instance once I passed it to the `add_error_listener` function? Of course, I cannot clone the listener when passing it to the parser. (Note that `add_error_listener` is part of the AntLR rust lib)

Comment: hint: Store the `RefCell<Vec>` outside the listener, and store a reference to it in the listener.

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks for the hint. It actually worked even if I had to wrap the outer RefCell into a Rc to avoid cloning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on the suggestion from @PitaJ, I came up with this solution:

```
    let errors = Rc::new(RefCell::new(vec![]));
    let listener = MyErrorListener::new(&errors.clone()); // MyListener has a property errors: Rc<RefCell<Vec<isize>>>
    parser.add_error_listener(Box::new(listener));
    let res = parser.query();
    errors.as_ref().clone().into_inner().clone() // here I can access to the inner object and return it
```

Hope this can help someone else.